# connection line grayed out in iBooks Author

Tags: macos, ibooks-author

I went to menu-format-text and all that but the thing is the box grayed out totally.

At this point, all I could actually click on was the hide and show thing but of course I can't see anything really. [what is the hide and show thing]

I am not really good at handling Mac terminology and don't know where to start.

Comment: We're going to need you to edit in a better description or perhaps upload a picture showing the issue. Just add a link to the comments and @bmike me and I'll help embed it. Also, editing carefully for grammar shows you have thought through the issue and makes it more likely someone will spend effort to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

The option to connect boxes does not work with the title page.  Create two new boxes within the document, select both boxes using the Command Key then try connecting the boxes  again.

Answer (score 0):

If you search iBooks Author help for the term "format text", the first three help articles will help describe the controls and show you step by step how to use the on screen controls to format text.

Trying to guess what the "hide and show thing" and guide you through linking text flows is extremely difficult to do without sharing a screen or at least a picture of your task.